# Can I set my own subject in the task notification email

Tags: email, tasks

I have created a workflow which is creating tasks and sets the body, subject and assigned to some user or group.

SharePoint is adding some extra text to my subject. This is the text:

"has been assigned to you"

I would like to change this extra text. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do here would be to create your own custom workflow (or event receiver) that generates and sends the email (and disabled the default one).  It is possible to modify the XML templates used by SharePoint for the task alert emails (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/07/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx).  However, this modifies SharePoint files on the hard drive.  This is both unsupported by Microsoft and can get overwritten with updates.

Comment: The reason why I would do this, is because the dutch translation of the task alert subject is not correct. Is there also another way to fix this?

Comment: SharePoint does have SOME of its translation strings externalized.  You might be able to find what you are looking for here: (2013) C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Resources, (2010) C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Resources.  Again, those files would get overwritten during updates, but you may be able to find the correct string to replace in there.  If it isn't here, it is probably baked into an assembly and you wouldn't be able to change that.